# Handling a VB.NET event in C# - Type Mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events

I have an event being generated in VB.NET code. This event is not editable, so I have to work with it as-is. The signature is:

```
Public Event CalibrateResult(ByVal BrValue As Single, ByVal TestType As Integer, ByVal TestTemp As Decimal)
```

I have a method set up in C# at a higher level to catch this:

```
public void OnDeviceCalibrateResult(Single BrValue, Int32 TestType, Decimal TestTemp)
{ ... }
```

However, when I actually try to assign the handler, I get an error message:

```
m_oDevice.CalibrateResult += new cDevice_Control.CalibrateResultEventHandler(OnDeviceCalibrateResult);

No overload for 'OnDeviceCalibrateResult' matches delegate 'SerDeviceComm.cDevice_Control.CalibrateResultEventHandler'
```

I have also tried 'int' and 'Int16' for the integer argument.  What types should I be using here?

Comment: What is `CatchDeviceCalibrateResult`?

Comment: That was a mispaste - should be 'OnDeviceCalibrateResult' - i corrected above. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried letting VS auto-complete the event instead of manually creating the event?

Comment: What is the definition of `SerDeviceComm.cDevice_Control.CalibrateResultEventHandler`? Does it have the same parameters as the event `CalibrateResult`? If so, there shouldn't be any errors.

Comment: Auto-complete fills in cDevice_Control.CalibrateResultEventHandler(void) but it won't auto-complete the arguments in OnDeviceCalibrateResult.

Comment: In your VB code, try explicitly declaring both event and delegate instead of the VB shortcut: Public Delegate Sub CalibrateResultEventHandler(ByVal BrValue As Single, ByVal TestType As Integer, ByVal TestTemp As Decimal)
Public Event CalibrateResult As CalibrateResultEventHandler

Comment: I don't know enough VB.net, but try a decompiler like dotPeek - https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ - to decompile the VB.net assembly to C# and see what it generates.